# WP not recognizing custom post type / template

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

I've created a custom post type:

```
   $args = array(
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => __( 'Prosjekter' ),
      'singular_name' => __( 'Prosjekt' ),
      'add_new' => __('Nytt prosjekt')
    ),
    'public' => false,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'taxonomies' => array('category'),
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes','post_tag' ),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'prosjekter')
  );
 register_post_type( 'project',$args);
```

Then I've created this template file:

```
single-project.php
```

But when I open a project it's not using the template. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change public to true. Else if not to be public then I'm not sure you can use or need a template. If you do need some sort of interface for administrators that works via theme. Then I think you need to set public to true and use other values to prevent public querying etc

See Wordpress.org http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type